# Is there a better way to write this if-else block?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, binary-search-tree, conditional-operator

I am writing some code for a Binary Search Tree where each node has a `left` and a `right` child pointer. In my `delete` function I have the following code.

```
if (!current.left && !current.right) {
  if (parent.left === current) {
    parent.left = null;
  } else {
    parent.right = null;
  }
} else {
  if (parent.left === current) {
    parent.left = current.left ? current.left : current.right;
  } else {
    parent.right = current.left ? current.left : current.right;
  }
}
```

Twice I have some block with the following syntax:

```
if (someCondition) {
  parent.left = x;
} else {
  parent.right = x;
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to write this (maybe a one-liner)? I am not sure if there is a ternary operator syntax I can use here because I have `parent.left = x` in the `if` block and `parent.right = x` in the `else` block. I am not keen on all of these `if-else` blocks used in this function.

Here is the entire code snippet.

```
const getInOrderSuccessor = (root, node) => {
  let successorParent = null;
  let successor = null;
  let previous = null;
  let current = root;

  while (current) {
    if (node.value < current.value) {
      successorParent = previous;
      successor = current;
      previous = current;
      current = current.left;
    } else {
      previous = current;
      current = current.right;
    }
  }
  return [successor, successorParent];
};

const deleteNode = (root, value) => {
  let current = root;
  let parent = null;
  while (current) {
    if (value === current.value) break;
    parent = current;
    current = value < current.value ? current.left : current.right;
  }

  // If 2 child, deal with that first
  if (current.left && current.right) {
    const [successor, successorParent] = getInOrderSuccessor(root, current);
    current.value = successor.value;
    current = successor;
    parent = successorParent;
  }

  if (!current.left && !current.right) {
    if (parent.left === current) {
      parent.left = null;
    } else {
      parent.right = null;
    }
  } else {
    if (parent.left === current) {
      parent.left = current.left ? current.left : current.right;
    } else {
      parent.right = current.left ? current.left : current.right;
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `parent.left = x` and `parent.right = x` you could store the property name in a variable and use `parent[direction] = x` instead.

For your specific scenario it also helps that the `parent.left === current` check is made in both the if and else-block. This means we can move it outside the conditional.

```
const direction = parent.left === current ? "left" : "right";
if (!current.left && !current.right) {
  parent[direction] = null;
} else {
  parent[direction] = current.left ? current.left : current.right;
}
```

You can further simplify this by reworking your logic.

```
if (!a && !b) {
  variable = null;
} else {
  variable = a ? a : b;
}
```

Can be changed into:

```
if (a) {
  variable = a;
} else if (b) {
  variable = b;
} else {
  variable = null;
}
```

Which can also be written as:

```
variable = a || b || null;
```

Resulting in the following solution:

```
const direction = parent.left === current ? "left" : "right";
parent[direction] = current.left || current.right || null;
```

Comment: Brilliant. I don't think I ever would have made the jump from that `if (!a && !b)` block to your `if-else if-else` block. Thank you!

Comment: @Espresso For me it helps to zoom out a bit and see what the intention of the code is, rather than what it is currently doing. I didn't put much effort in explaining why you can make this step, but I hope the simplified example shows that if you first check `a`, then `b`, then the only thing left is `!a && !b` (which is the *else*).

Comment: Yes I think taking a step back helps a lot here. Once I rewrote my code in generic terms `a` and `b` and followed your steps I could then see how you arrived at your solution. I will try and remember this for the future! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one.

whenever you have something like `z = y?y:x` you should replace it with `||` operator  like this `z = y || x`
And also you can write common conditions.

```
if (parent.left === current) {
  parent.left = (!current.left && !current.right) ? null : (current.left || current.right);
} else {
  parent.right = !(!current.left && !current.right) ? null : (current.left || current.right);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option that satisfies your criteria, though style-wise I like what you've written better than this :-)

```js
function chooseWhichToMakeNull(object, condition) {
  const field = condition ? 'left' : 'right';
  object[field] = null;
}

const obj = { left: 5, right: 10 };
chooseWhichToMakeNull(obj, true);
console.log(obj);
```